# SQL group_concat function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

If there is a table called employee

```
EmpID           EmpName
----------      -------------
1               Mary
1               John
1               Sam
2               Alaina
2               Edward
```

Result I need in this format:

```
EmpID           EmpName
----------      -------------
1               Mary, John, Sam
2               Alaina, Edward
```

Q: this record is in same `Employee` table. I have almost no experience using UDFs, stored procedures, I need to be done this thing through query.Is this possible without using UDFs, SP's.

Comment: Which SQL Server version? Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 @ BartekR

Comment: @OlegDok as I am new to sql I have tried that post but I am confused for column_names in that..:(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. FOR XML PATH [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005) and [article](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html)
2. CLR User defined aggregate
3. for sql server prior version 2005 - temporary tables

**An example of #1**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (EmpId INT, EmpName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @t VALUES
(1, 'Mary'),(1, 'John'),(1, 'Sam'),(2, 'Alaina'),(2, 'Edward')
SELECT distinct
    EmpId,
    (
        SELECT EmpName+','
        FROM @t t2
        WHERE t2.EmpId = t1.EmpId
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) Concatenated
FROM @t t1
```

How to strip the final comma - is on your own

**A CLR aggregate c# code for #2**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.IO;

namespace DatabaseAssembly
{
    [Serializable]
    [SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined,
        IsInvariantToNulls = true,
        IsInvariantToDuplicates = true,
        IsInvariantToOrder = true,
        MaxByteSize = -1)]
    public struct StringJoin : IBinarySerialize
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> AggregationList
        {
            get
            {
                if (_list == null)
                    _list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                return _list;
            }
        }
        private Dictionary<string, string> _list;

        public void Init()
        {

        }

        public void Accumulate(SqlString Value)
        {
            if (!Value.IsNull)
                AggregationList[Value.Value.ToLowerInvariant()] = Value.Value;

        }

        public void Merge(StringJoin Group)
        {
            foreach (var key in Group.AggregationList.Keys)
                AggregationList[key] = Group.AggregationList[key];
        }

        public SqlChars Terminate()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var value in AggregationList.Values)
                sb.Append(value);
            return new SqlChars(sb.ToString());
        }

        #region IBinarySerialize Members

        public void Read(System.IO.BinaryReader r)
        {

            try
            {
                while (true)
                    AggregationList[r.ReadString()] = r.ReadString();
            }
            catch (EndOfStreamException)
            {

            }
        }

        public void Write(System.IO.BinaryWriter w)
        {
            foreach (var key in AggregationList.Keys)
            {
                w.Write(key);
                w.Write(AggregationList[key]);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: superb temporarily table works...Thnx...:)..Now i have to work on excluding the last comma..

Answer (score 14):

The chosen answer from @OlegDok's may return the correct result. But the performance can be terrible. This test scenario will illustrate it.

Creation of a temp table:

```
CREATE table #temp (EmpId INT, EmpName VARCHAR(100))
;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d,N e,N f)
INSERT #temp
SELECT EmpId, EmpName FROM (values(1, 'Mary'),(1, 'John'),(1, 'Sam')) x(EmpId, EmpName)
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT top 2000 N FROM tally) y
UNION ALL
SELECT EmpId, EmpName FROM (values(2, 'Alaina'),(2, 'Edward')) x(EmpId, EmpName)
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT top 2000 N FROM tally) y
```

This is only 10.000 rows. But lots of identical EmpId.

This query in Oleg's answer took 64 seconds on my database.

```
SELECT distinct
    EmpId,
    (
        SELECT EmpName+','
        FROM #temp t2
        WHERE t2.EmpId = t1.EmpId
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) Concatenated
FROM #temp t1
```

Distinct is not the correct way of cleaning up rows in this situation. 
To avoid this cartesian join, reduce the initial number of IDs before joining like this.

This is the correct way of handling this:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT distinct EmpId
  FROM #temp
)
SELECT 
    EmpId,
    STUFF((
        SELECT ','+EmpName
        FROM #temp t2
        WHERE t2.EmpId = t1.EmpId
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1,1,'') Concatenated
FROM CTE t1
```

This takes less than 1 second

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no `GROUP_CONCAT` function in MSSQL. This [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) shows different ways of concactenating row values.

**Concatenating values when the number of items is small and known upfront**

```
SELECT CategoryId,
       MAX( CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
       MAX( CASE seq WHEN 2 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
       MAX( CASE seq WHEN 3 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END ) + ', ' +
       MAX( CASE seq WHEN 4 THEN ProductName ELSE '' END )
  FROM ( SELECT p1.CategoryId, p1.ProductName,
                ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p2
                   WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId
                     AND p2.ProductName <= p1.ProductName )
           FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p1 ) D ( CategoryId, ProductName, seq )
 GROUP BY CategoryId ;
```

[More ways on this link.](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the example given in the beginning:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp_name,
STUFF(
(SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(proj_id)
FROM project_members AS t1 
WHERE t1.emp_name = t2.emp_name
FOR XML PATH (''))
, 1, 1, '')
FROM project_members t2
```