# concat column value in single value 

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)
>   [Does T-SQL have an aggregate function to concatenate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings)
>   [SQL group_concat function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server)

I've tabular structure like this

```
    Table1
Col1     Col2

val1     text1

val1     text2

val1     text3

val1     text4

val1     text5
```

Now i want the output **using a simple sql statement(No procedure No function)**
in this form like this.

statement like

> select col2 where col1 = 'val1'

output like

> **text1,text2,text3,text4,text5**

Comment: This will help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: This is my preferred solution. It avoids errors when special characters are encountered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings/5031297#5031297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @var1 varchar(200)
SELECT @var1 = COALESCE(@var1 + ', ', '') +  Col2 from #table1 where Col1 = 'val1'
Select @var1
```