# SQL Server : GROUP BY clause to get comma-separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL group_concat function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server)

I am looking to create a query but somehow I am unable to do so. Can anyone please help me out here?

The original data

```
ID    ReportId     Email
1     1            a@a.com
2     2            b@b.com
3     1            c@c.com
4     3            d@d.com
5     3            e@e.com
```

I want to group by `ReportId`, but all the email should be comma separated. So the result should be:

```
ReportId     Email
1            a@a.com, c@c.com
2            b@b.com
3            d@d.com, e@e.com
```

What is the best way to do this?

I am trying the group by clause but if there is any other thing then i am open to implement that also. I really appreciate your time and help on this. Thank you.

Comment: and [sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2017 you can use `SELECT ReportId, STRING_AGG(a.Email, ', ') as Email
FROM your_table a
GROUP BY ReportId`

Answer (score 221, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT ReportId, Email = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Email
           FROM your_table b 
           WHERE b.ReportId = a.ReportId 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM your_table a
GROUP BY ReportId
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c7d6/2)

Comment: @joe is there any other efficient way of doing this? I have a table with 30,000 records and it's taking 20 seconds...

Comment: If you don't want the space with the comma, you need to do 1,1,'' instead of 1,2,''

Comment: could you add some text about how this works?

Comment: I know its very old post, but if you are using SQL server 2017, you can use STRING_AGG() function.

Comment: Fiddle with STRING_AGG() [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/27b86/751)

Comment: @PaulNakitare You should add this as answer. Simplest solution. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT  [ReportId], 
        SUBSTRING(d.EmailList,1, LEN(d.EmailList) - 1) EmailList
FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT [ReportId]
            FROM Table1
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT [Email] + ', ' 
            FROM Table1 AS B 
            WHERE A.[ReportId] = B.[ReportId]
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (EmailList)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3192a/1)

Comment: This worked for a complex join whereas the other would not. Underrated.