# SQL use assignment inside select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to turn my IP address into set of 3-digit numbers, left padded with 0.  I can easily do that like so:

```sql
DECLARE @merged VARCHAR(15);
SELECT @marged = COALESCE(@merged + '.', '') + RIGHT('000' + [value], 3)
FROM string_split(ip_address, '.');
```

But now I want to do something like that within a broader select statement.

```
SELECT Name, @merged AS IP_Address, Mac_Address
FROM some_table
```

I'm not sure how to get the `@merged` part there though when I'm querying against a full table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the comma values:

[Return Comma separated values SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631009/return-comma-separated-values-sql)

To get them grouped:

[Comma Separated list of rows of a column with group by on other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494975/comma-separated-list-of-rows-of-a-column-with-group-by-on-other-columns)

http://www.peteonsoftware.com/index.php/2009/12/11/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-a-sql-grouping/

Comment: That's still got that same problem of how to do the `select @merged =` part of the query though from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You have a specific problem with IP addresses, so you can  use [`parse_name()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax):

```
SELECT Name, 
       (left('000' + parse_name(Mac_Address, 4), 3) + '.' +
        left('000' + parse_name(Mac_Address, 3), 3) + '.' +
        left('000' + parse_name(Mac_Address, 2), 3) + '.' +
        left('000' + parse_name(Mac_Address, 1), 3) 
       ) as ip_address,
      Mac_Address
FROM some_table;
```

This is going to be simpler and better performing that other solutions use string aggregation.

Comment: @Gargoyle . . . `parsename()` has existed as long as I've used SQL Server.  I think it was in SQL Server 2000.  Here is an old reference:  http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data.