# SQL - Turn relationship IDs into a delimited list

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Say I have a table with the following data:

[image: example data]

You can see columns a, b, & c have a lot of redundancies.  I would like those redundancies removed while preserving the site_id info.  If I exclude the site_id column from the query, I can get part of the way there by doing `SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c from my_table`.

What would be ideal is a SQL query that could turn the site IDs relevant to a permutation of a/b/c into a delimited list, and output something like the following:

[image: desired output]

Is it possible to do that with a SQL query? Or will I have to export everything and use a different tool to remove the redundancies?

The data is in a SQL Server DB, though I'd also be curious how to do the same thing with postgres, if the process is different.

Comment: For MSSQL, you have [COALESCE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/194887/342740) and for PostgreSQL you have [string_agg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43944/342740) but depending on version different methods. Don't forget search is your friend ;)

Comment: i know an easy way to do this is SQL but not sure about postgres.  http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Comment: here is one way to do it with SQL Server http://stackoverflow.com/a/1785923/215752

Comment: Wow, I thought what I was trying to do was kind of odd (and wasn't having much luck searching)... Apparently it's not all that unusual.  I was just searching for the wrong stuff.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can use the FOR XML trick as found in the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668528/sql-server-group-by-clause-to-get-comma-separated-values) post.

For your scenario it would look something like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c,  SiteIds = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + SiteId
           FROM your_table t2 
           WHERE t2.a = t1.a AND t2.b = t1.b AND t2.c = t1.c
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM your_table t1
GROUP BY a, b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres:

```
select a,b,c, string_agg(site_id::varchar, ',')
from my_table
group by a,b,b;
```

I assume `site_id` is a number, and as `string_agg()` only accepts character value, this needs to be casted to a character string for the aggregation. This is what `site_id::text` does. Alternatively you can use the `cast()` operator: `string_agg(cast(site_id as varchar), ',')`

Answer (score 0):

This is generally known as String Aggregation. Many RDBMS's have the ability baked in, and many others don't.

In Postgres you just use the `STRING_AGG(<field>, <delimiter>)` function, and make sure to add a GROUP BY for your non-aggregated fields. Simple stuff.

In SQL Server.. not so pretty, but folks have functions and whatnot that will allow you to do this ([like in this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings))