# how do i group records in mysql table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in MySQL which has `group_id` and `name` columns (the table has multiple users divided into groups using `group_id`).

[table design and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHnrs.png)

I want to display these users in the html table using grouping of names.

[grouping of names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsmJa.png)

I used the following MySQL query, but it does not do the job.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `teams` 
WHERE 1
GROUP BY 
    group_id
```

What should I do to get the output using PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Here is the Possible [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668528/sql-server-group-by-clause-to-get-comma-separated-values) of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use group_concat for the query

```
SELECT group_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
from teams 
group by group_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function for that:

```
SELECT
    group_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) AS teams
FROM
    teams
GROUP BY
    group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below SQL query

```
select 
id,group_concat(concat(`name`) separator ',')
as Result from teams group by group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `GROUP_CONCAT(name)` in the examples above and you get your query back you can do the following in php to loop through the results.

> **SELECT**
>   ***group_id***,
>   **group_concat(*name*) AS *team* FROM**
>   **your_table GROUP BY**
>   ***group_id***

```
$html = [];
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $html []= "<div>";
        $html []= "GROUP ID:" . $row['group_id'];
        $html []= "TEAM:" . $row['team'];
    $html []= "</div>";
}
echo join("", $html);
```

***Note:*** I am using a **$html** array here because cause its more memory efficient to use an array for large scale string concatenations than it is to use **.=** string operator.