# Grouping by commas

Tags: sql, group-by, psql

I want to accomplish the following:

```
ID  serviceaccess
11  Value1
11  Value2
11  Value3
22  Value2
22  Value1
22  Value1


ID
11 value1, value2, value3
22 value2, value1, value1
```

But I can't use stuff STUFF(( because my system doesn't support it. 
This link doesn't really help. I have tried everything so far, but ran out of ideas. Thanks

[SQL Server : GROUP BY clause to get comma-separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668528/sql-server-group-by-clause-to-get-comma-separated-values)

Thought about this, but doest' work. Please help:

```
WITH RecurRanked ( dbid, rnk, serviceaccess)
             AS ( 
                SELECT t.t1.dbid, t.t1.rnk, t.t2.serviceaccess || ', ' || t.t1.serviceaccess 
                FROM t.t1
                INNER JOIN t.t2  ON t.t1.dbid = RecurRanked.dbid AND t.t1.rnk = RecurRanked.rnk + 1)
SELECT dbid, MAX(serviceaccess)
FROM RecurRanked
GROUP BY dbid;


    SELECT t.t1.dbid, t.t1.rnk, t.t2.serviceaccess || ', ' || t.t1.serviceaccess 
                FROM t.t1
                INNER JOIN t.t2  ON t.t1.dbid = t.t2.dbid AND t.t1.rnk = t.t2.rnk + 1
```

Comment: Postgres doesn't support `stuff`.  Here's the equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent

Comment: yeah, thank you but those functions don't work either. ERROR: function string_agg(character varying, "unknown") does not exist

Comment: Are there only 3 values in all of your rows?

Comment: No, there are more than 3, up to 70 values.

Comment: Can you confirm which database/version you are using?  Your tags suggest Postgres, but I am not 100% sure if that was your intent.

Comment: I am using an mpp database. http://www.actian.com/products/big-data-analytics-platforms-with-hadoop/matrix-mpp-analytics-databases/