# Inner join based on comma separated field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have two tables `InvoiceLocations` and `PCInvoiceLocation` with respective data.

[image]

i just want a output like following.

[image]

Please help.

Code from comments:

```
declare @@LocationId nvarchar(50)='1,2' 
declare @@sql nvarchar(Max) 
Declare @@Output table(Code nvarchar(10) not null) 
Set @@sql='SELECT Code FROM invoiceLocations WHERE Id IN ('+@LocationId+')' 
insert @@Output(Code) 
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: yes trying to execute the following query but not working for me

Comment: declare @@LocationId nvarchar(50)='1,2'
declare @@sql nvarchar(Max)
Declare @@Output table(Code nvarchar(10) not null)
Set @@sql='SELECT Code FROM invoiceLocations WHERE Id IN ('+@LocationId+')'
insert @@Output(Code) exec sp_executesql @sql

Comment: SO is not a free coding service.  Post your code.  If it doesn't work, we can help.

Comment: Don't put your code in comment section.  Modify your post.  No one is going to read that.

Comment: @PramodThakur - Please post your tried query in your body of the post.

Comment: I am trying to store locationname in a table variable but i am not able to store that.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir i am not able to edit my question. i have shared what i am trying to do in comment.

Comment: Please take that Locations column and normalise it into its own table that has a 1:many relationship with `pcinvoicelocation`. You're making a massive rod for your own back putting csv data into a column, with an expectation that it's going to be simple and fast to work with. This is not how relational databases are supposed to work

Comment: PramodThakur this can be achieved in 3 steps: First split the Locations field into rows, then Join these rows with the InvoiceLocations table to get related values, finally Aggregate the results into on comma seperated filed. I posted a detailed answer, you can take a look

Answer (score 2):

**Create Testing Environment**

First i used the following command to create the testing environment

```
CREATE TABLE InvoiceLocations (ID int,CODE varchar(3), VALUE varchar(3));
CREATE TABLE PCInvoiceLOcation (ID int,CategoryID INT, Locations varchar(50),DefaultLocationID int);


INSERT INTO InvoiceLocations(ID,CODE,VALUE)
VALUES(1,'BFC','BFC'),
(2,'BRH','BRH'),
(3,'BRP','BRP'),
(4,'BCC','BCC')

INSERT INTO PCInvoiceLOcation(ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID)
VALUES(1,1,'1,2',1),
(2,2,'2,3',2),
(3,3,'2,1',1),
(4,4,'4',4)
```

## Solution

You can achieve this in 3 steps:

1. First split the `Locations` field into rows
2. Join these rows with the `InvoiceLocations` table to get related values
3. Aggregate the results into on comma seperated filed

**First split the `Locations` field into rows**

```
;with tmp(ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  DataItem , Data) as (
        select ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID, 
                CAST( LEFT(Locations, CHARINDEX(',',Locations+',')-1) as varchar(5)),
                STUFF(Locations, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Locations+','), '')
        from PCInvoiceLOcation
    union all
        select ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  
                CAST(LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1) AS Varchar(5)),
                STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
        from tmp
        where Data > '')
```

**Join these rows with the InvoiceLocations table to get related values**

```
select tmp.ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  DataItem , InvoiceLocations.VALUE
from tmp
INNER JOIN InvoiceLocations ON tmp.DataItem = InvoiceLocations.ID
```

**Aggregate the results into on comma seperated filed**

```
Select ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  
            STUFF((SELECT ', ' + VALUE
                       FROM Tmp2 AS T3 
                       WHERE T3.ID = tmp2.ID 
                      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    FROM tmp2 
    GROUP BY ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID
```

**The Whole Query will looks like**

```
;with tmp(ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  DataItem , Data) as (
        select ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID, 
                CAST( LEFT(Locations, CHARINDEX(',',Locations+',')-1) as varchar(5)),
                STUFF(Locations, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Locations+','), '')
        from PCInvoiceLOcation
    union all
        select ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  
                CAST(LEFT(Data, CHARINDEX(',',Data+',')-1) AS Varchar(5)),
                STUFF(Data, 1, CHARINDEX(',',Data+','), '')
        from tmp
        where Data > '')
    ,tmp2(ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  DataItem , VALUE) AS (
        select tmp.ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  DataItem , InvoiceLocations.VALUE
        from tmp
        INNER JOIN InvoiceLocations ON tmp.DataItem = InvoiceLocations.ID) 

        Select ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID,  
                STUFF((SELECT ', ' + VALUE
                           FROM Tmp2 AS T3 
                           WHERE T3.ID = tmp2.ID 
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
        FROM tmp2 
        GROUP BY ID,CategoryID,Locations,DefaultLocationID
```

*Result:*

[image]

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94fc89/3/0)

**References**

- [SQL Server : GROUP BY clause to get comma-separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668528/sql-server-group-by-clause-to-get-comma-separated-values)
- [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)