# Gridview to concatenate column A with the same column B value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, group-by

I would like to ask if below output is possible in the ASP.Net gridview. Basically, I would like to group by all user's with the same role.

Returned Result:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        USER         |       ROLE       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       User 1        |     Requestor    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       User 2        |     Verifier     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       User 3        |     Verifier     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       User 4        |     Approver     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Output:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        USER         |       ROLE       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       User 1        |     Requestor    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   User 2, User 3    |     Verifier     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       User 4        |     Approver     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Yes it is. You just have to manipulate your data source so it contains the correct data you need and then bind it to the grid.

Comment: This is exactly what you need.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668528/sql-server-group-by-clause-to-get-comma-separated-values

Comment: @GaganDeep I need to manipulate it on the gridview side since the SP I'm using is also being used by other modules

Comment: Can't you do it at code behind?