# How to list and group same records in diffrent columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i have one table has 2 columns like

```
group_id   product_id
2          65
2          50
2          30
2          60
2          42
5          40
5          42
6          30
6          65
6          60
7          90
7          40
```

I want to get list of product id's records in the same group id

Comment: And what results do you want?

Comment: list of products added to same group id

Comment: @mrking You're talking about a comma separated list of product_ids by group_id?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified your desired output. But if you're wanting a comma separated list by group you can do something like this answer from the below StackOverflow threads:

MySQL

```
SELECT t.group_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.product_id) AS product_id_group
FROM [YOURTABLE] t
GROUP BY t.id, t.product_id;
```

[MySQL Results as comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)

SQL Sever

```
SELECT group_id, product_id = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + product_id
           FROM [YOURTABLE] t1
           WHERE t1.group_id = t2.group_id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM [YOURTABLE] t2
GROUP BY group_id
```

[SQL Server : GROUP BY clause to get comma-separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668528/sql-server-group-by-clause-to-get-comma-separated-values)

This will return a result set like:

```
group_id    product_id
2           65, 50, 30, 60, 42
5           40, 42
6           30, 65, 60
7           90, 40
```

Comment: @mrking See the MySQL edit and if that doesn't work, please provide an error message.