# Select row of data based on several conditions from other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

I'm using SQL Server, and I have this data:

```
NO_PO_MYSAP ID_PLANNING_DETAIL ITEM BL
5501        13683              6    2019-11-28
5501        13683              7    2019-11-28
1101        13685              6    2019-12-10
1101        13685              6    2019-12-11
1101        13685              7    2019-12-10
1101        13685              7    2019-12-11
```

You can see that they have different no. of rows under the same **NO_PO_MYSAP**, because when I. select distinct, **BL** for **13685** has different values.

What I want is, if **BL** returns different values under similar **NO_PO_MYSAP**, I want those values to be sticked together so I still get 2 rows of data as in **ID_PLANNING_DETAIL = 13683** (no. of rows depend on no. of **ITEM**, in this case they are 6 and 7).

So the return data will look like this:

```
NO_PO_MYSAP ID_PLANNING_DETAIL ITEM BL
5501        13683              6    2019-11-28
5501        13683              7    2019-11-28
1101        13685              6    2019-12-10, 2019-12-11
1101        13685              7    2019-12-10, 2019-12-11
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : GROUP BY clause to get comma-separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668528/sql-server-group-by-clause-to-get-comma-separated-values)

Comment: How is this any different from your previous question [SQL: Select row of data based on several conditions from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069553/sql-server-select-row-of-data-based-on-several-conditions-from-other-columns)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here this demo can help 
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c7d6/2)

```
SELECT distinct NO_PO_MYSAP, 
                ID_PLANNING_DETAIL,
                ITEM,  
                BL = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + bl_date
               FROM Table_bl bl  -- your table name from bl_date --
               WHERE bl.ID = A.ID
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM   v_temp_iseecargo_planning A 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_trx_planning_detail B 
              ON A.id_planning = B.id_planning  AND B.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_trx_lifting C 
              ON A.id_planning = C.id_planning AND C.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_trx_lifting_detail D 
              ON C.id_lifting = D.id_lifting AND D.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_md_port E 
              ON B.id_port_loading = E.id_port AND E.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_md_port F 
              ON B.id_port_discharge = F.id_port AND F.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_md_item G 
              ON B.id_item = G.id_item AND G.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_trx_vessel_acceptance H 
              ON C.id_lifting = H.id_lifting AND H.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_md_vessel I 
              ON H.id_vessel = I.id_vessel AND I.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_md_uom J 
              ON B.id_uom = J.id_uom AND J.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN tbl_iseecargo_md_shipping_type K 
              ON id_shipping_type_temp = K.id_shipping_type AND K.CHANGEID <> 'D'
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id_planning_detail, 
                                  no_po_mysap 
                  FROM 
       tbl_iseecargo_trx_procurement_detail
       where CHANGEID <> 'D') L 
              ON b.id_planning_detail = L.id_planning_detail 
WHERE  A.ID_PLANNING in (13683, 13685) and B.id_uom = '3'
order by ALD_AWAL desc;
```

Comment: Hi, it is working to return 2 rows now, but, returned value only one value (not concatenated). The origin type is date, i convert to varchar. Still, only one value return, not as expected with comma between

Comment: can you create a demo in sqlFiddle?

Comment: HI I've made the demo.. you can see its showing strings of concatenated date, but its duplicating. In my real case, its not even showing concatenated string, only one value per row data.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8d29/11/0

Comment: logically yes.. but still not working in real db :(((

Comment: sorry without testing data it's hard for anyone to find logical bug

Comment: Hm.. can you help me again? What if the data looks like this   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66bc39/2.
I want the data to look like as before i changed the data structure (2 rows with concated date)

Comment: I think output is correct as Data here check with your example data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b3d7e/1

Comment: I've changed the data again now.. please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/43dd6/1.
Here under PO_NO_MYSAP 1101 i still get 4 rows..

Comment: as i said before as per data it's showing correct! do you also want to merge ID_PLAN/ITEM?

Comment: Sorry.. i dont understand. I am hoping that under NO_PO_MYSAP 1101, i would only get 2 rows containing NO_PO_MYSAP 1101;ITEM 6;BL DATE A,B and NO_PO_MYSAP 1101;ITEM 7;BL DATE A,B. I dont know if maybe we can just disregard ID_PLAN, but yes it is different. How?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207325/discussion-between-jov-and-ravi-makwana).

Comment: No need to accept answer if it's not resolve your problem :)