# How to append database values to JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON which lists the values from database. Below is the JSON data of 2 rows from the database.

```
[{"Name":"P1","Description":"pd1","Value":"v1","Attribute":"a1"},{"Name":"P1","Description":"pd1","Value":"v2","Attribute":"a2"}]
```

database values are the result of a left join query. Only 'Value' and 'Attribute' fields are different. Can I append that fields to JSON instead of multiple sets of record? I know there is 'push' to do this, but I am unaware where and how to use this in my code. below is the code for fetching values from db and serializing the values.

```
GetProfileDataService GetProfileDataService = new BokingEngine.MasterDataService.GetProfileDataService();
IEnumerable<ProfileData> ProfileDetails = GetProfileDataService.GetList(new ProfileSearchCriteria { Name = strProfileName });
JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string strSerProfileDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(ProfileDetails);
context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
context.Response.Write(strSerProfileDetails);
```

Below is my getJSON

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('ProfileHandler.ashx', { 'ProfileName': 'Profile 1' }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            alert(v.Attribute+' : '+v.Value);               
        });            
    });
});
```

Please help me here.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the code above is actually Javascript?  Javascript isn't strongly typed...

Comment: The code above is not a Javascript. the code above will return a JSON data to a getJSON ajax method

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it properly.  My bad.

Comment: What `json` you get? Try to use `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do.

Store value and attribute as arrays:

`[{"Name":"P1","Description":"pd1","Value":["v1", "v2"],"Attribute":["a1", "a2"]}]`

Or store them as a 'symbol'-separated string:

`[{"Name":"P1","Description":"pd1","Value":"v1;v2"],"Attribute":"a1;a2"]}]`

In order to use the first case, you'll have to try and figure out how to format the ProfileDetails in order to have javaScriptSerializer.Serialize parse it correctly. You will likely have to convert your data first in order for this to work (i.e. convert *value* and *attribute* to arrays).

For the second case to work you could modify your GetProfileDataService.GetList method so that values and attributes are merged to symbol-separated strings (something like this: [GROUP BY to combine/concat a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/sql-group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column/15154723#comment21339144_15154723))