# Join string and add character between them in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as below:

**agents**

```
id    |  name
1     |  abc
2     |  def
```

**stores**

```
id | name | agent_id
1  | aaa  | 1
2  | bbb  | 1
```

**I want to result like this:**

```
agent_name | store_name
  abc      | aaa|bbb
```

**Not:**

```
agent_name | store_name
  abc      |   aaa
  abc      |   bbb
```

Which query can help me do this? I know `concat` function but I don't know how to add characters `|` between strings.

Comment: Please show what you tried so far. Any SQL scripts?

Comment: I think the following link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/sql-group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**GROUP_CONCAT(expr)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
  a.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR '|') store_name
FROM
  agents a 
  JOIN stores s 
    ON (a.id = s.agent_id) 
GROUP BY a.id
```

**Note Be aware of that the result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) system variable, which has a default value of 1024**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT a.name agent_name,CONCAT(a.name,'|',b.name)store_name 
FROM agents a 
INNER JOIN stores b ON a.id=b.id
```

CONCAT function is used to concatenate two strings to form a single string.
In this "name" from agents table is concatenated with a string '|' and "name" from stores table using join to get the required result

Comment: give some explanation also