# How to Combine Rows value based on group by column name

Tags: sql

I have the table in below format,

```
schemecode  TotalValue  DateVal
A                  1    2014-07-09
AA                 1    2014-07-09
AAA                1    2014-09-25
AAB                1    2014-09-24
ABC                1    2014-09-25
ABD                1    2014-08-25
```

I need the result like below format,

```
schemecode  TotalValue  DateVal
A,AA             2      2014-07-09
AAA,ABC          2      2014-09-25
AAB              1      2014-09-24
ABD              1      2014-08-25
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: grouping by column name would group them by unique columns, your output logic isnt unique?

Comment: or do you want them grouped by dateval?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: same requirement is already available with answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/sql-group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 11g

```
select listagg(schemecode, ',') within group (order by schemecode) as codes, 
       sum(totalvalue), dateval
from your_table
group by dateval;
```

Oracle 10g

```
select wm_concat(schemecode) as codes, 
       sum(totalvalue), dateval
from your_table
group by dateval;
```

MySQL

```
select group_concat(schemecode, ',') as codes, 
       sum(totalvalue), dateval
from your_table
group by dateval;
```

SQL Server (not tested)

```
select codes = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + t2.schemecode
          FROM your_table t2
          WHERE t2.dateval = t.dateval
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''), 
       sum(t.totalvalue), t.dateval
from your_table t
group by t.dateval;
```

Comment: For the SQL Server it gives error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'. Just FYI :)