# Concatenate values that are grouped by a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-group-concat

I have the following table:

```
Code    Ref     Value
A1      Car     A
A1      Car     -
A1      Car     B
B2      Truck   CC
B2      Truck   D
B2      Truck   -
C3      Van     E
C3      Van     F
C3      Van     -
C3      Van     G
```

The goal I am trying to accomplish, is a concatenated string grouping all of the values together like this:

```
Code   Ref    Value
A1     Car    A-B
B2     Truck  CCD-
C3     Van    EF-G
```

I went off of the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/sql-group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column), but got nowhere. Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT [Table].[Code]
, [Table].[Ref]
, STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT [Value]
  FROM [Table2]
  FOR XML PATH ('')),1, 1,'') AS Values
FROM [Table]
LEFT JOIN [Table2] ON
[Table2].[Code] = [Table].[Code]
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Side note: without an ordering column, the concatenated result may (will) change for each run.  Will that be important?

Comment: It is not at this point. They can show in any order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have nothing linking your inner and outer references to `[Table]`, and you also need to make the outer reference distinct. Finally you need to either have no column name within your subquery, or it needs to be `[text()]`

```
SELECT  [Code]
        ,[Ref]
        ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT [Value] AS [text()]
                FROM [Table] AS T2
                WHERE T1.Code = T2.Code -- LINK HERE
                AND T2.Ref = T2.Ref     -- AND HERE
                FOR XML PATH ('')
                ),1, 1,'') AS [Values]
FROM    [Table] AS T1
GROUP BY T1.Code, T1.Ref; -- GROUP BY HERE
```

As an aside, you do not need to use `STUFF` as you have no delimiter, `STUFF` is typically used to remove the chosen delimiter from the start of the string. So when you have a string like `,value1,value2,value3`, `STUFF(string, 1, 1, '')` will replace the first character with `''` leaving you with `value1,value2,value3`.

You should also use the `value` xquery method to ensure you are not tripped up by special characters, if you don't and you try an concatenate `">>"` and `"<<"` you would not end up with `">><<"` as you might want, you would get `"&gt;&gt;&lt;&lt;"`, so a better query would be:

```
SELECT  t1.Code,
        t1.Ref,
        [Values] = (SELECT  DISTINCT [text()] = [Value]
                    FROM    [Table] AS t2
                    WHERE   T1.Code = T2.Code
                    AND     T2.Ref = T2.Ref
                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    [Table] AS T1
GROUP BY t1.Code, t1.Ref;
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

Based on the latest edit to the question it appears as though your `Value` column is coming from another table, linked to the first table by `Code`. If anything this makes your query simpler. You don't need the `JOIN`, but you still need to make sure that there is an expression to link the outer table to the inner table your subquery. I am assuming that the rows are unique in the first table, so you probably don't need the group by either:

```
SELECT  t1.Code,
        t1.Ref,
        [Values] = (SELECT  DISTINCT [text()] = t2.[Value]
                    FROM    [Table2] AS t2
                    WHERE   T1.Code = T2.Code
                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    [Table] AS T1;
```

---

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Code CHAR(2), Ref VARCHAR(10));
INSERT #Table1 VALUES ('A1', 'Car'), ('B2', 'Truck'), ('C3', 'Van');

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Code CHAR(2), Value VARCHAR(2));
INSERT #Table2
VALUES ('A1', 'A'), ('A1', '-'), ('A1', 'B'),
        ('B2', 'CC'), ('B2', 'D'), ('B2', '-'),
        ('C3', 'F'), ('C3', '-'), ('C3', 'G');

SELECT  t1.Code,
        t1.Ref,
        [Values] = (SELECT  DISTINCT [text()] = t2.[Value]
                    FROM    #Table2 AS t2
                    WHERE   T1.Code = T2.Code
                    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    #Table1 AS T1;
```

Comment: Okay, got this working, now if there was an index in `t2` that I need to order by, how would I go about this? I am getting an error 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.' when I add `ORDER BY t2.Index`, if I figure this part out, it's the answer I need.