# How to list rows which has the same value in the first column but different in the second? (SQL)

Tags: sql, list, sorting, sql-server-2005

I have a Data table like this:

```
Name        Grade
Jim          5
Jim          4
Charlie      3
```

I would like to get another Result table like this:

```
Name        Grades
Jim          5,4
Charlie      3
```

How can I list or sort out the grades of a child in one column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: It looks like you've duplicated this, which may help.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column