# Build a SQL Query to get Data in row form (all products name in row in-front one category)

Tags: sql

Need to build a SQL Query

I have two tables

```
tbl_cat
_________________
cat_id | cat_name
```

```
tbl_pro
__________________________
pro_id | pro_name | cat_id
```

now I need data in form of row

**e.g**

```
category name | pro name 1 | pro name 2 | pro name 3
```

OR

```
Category name | pro name 1 , pro name 2 , pro name 3
```

**my Query is**

```
SELECT ct.cat_name,
       cp.proname
FROM tbl_cat ct
JOIN tbl_pro cp
WHERE ct.cat_id=cp.cat_id;
```

and it shows result like this

```
_____________________________
cat Name | Pro Name 
cat Name | Pro Name 1 
cat Name | Pro Name 2
```

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and read the guidelines here for how to ask a good question.

Also, be sure to add your code so we can see what exactly has been done, and what exactly may need to be fixed or added.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to improve my question i think this is better than before

Comment: Get your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column

Comment: Unrelated, but: `JOIN tbl_pro cp WHERE ct.cat_id=cp.cat_id;` is invalid SQL. If you use `JOIN` you need to put the join condition in the `ON` clause. `JOIN tbl_pro cp ON ct.cat_id=cp.cat_id;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query"
SELECT tbl_cat.CatName, tbl_pro.ProName1, tbl_pro.ProName2, tbl_pro.ProName3
FROM tbl_cat
LEFT JOIN tbl_pro
ON tbl_cat.cat_id=tbl_pro.cat_id
";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "Category: " . $row[CatName] . " Product1: " . $row[ProName1] . " Product2: " . $row[ProName2] . " Product3: " . $row[ProName3];
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need it only in sql i know it easily handle in php :) but once again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlserver2008 R2 or above Try this:

```
select ct.cat_name,
    STUFF(
             (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + cp.pro_name
              FROM tbl_pro cp INNER JOIN tbl_cat ci on ci.cat_id=cp.cat_id
              where ci.cat_id = ct.cat_id                 
              FOR XML PATH (''))
              , 1, 1, '')  AS ProductList
    FROM tbl_cat ct
    GROUP BY ct.cat_name,ct.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DBMS, so this is for Postgres:

```
SELECT ct.cat_name, string_agg(cp.proname, ',')
FROM tbl_cat ct
  JOIN tbl_pro cp ON ct.cat_id=cp.cat_id
GROUP BY ct.cat_name
ORDER BY ct.cat_name;
```