# SQL to combine multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am currently writing a SQL script - takes a business term, and all related synonyms. What it does is creates multiple rows (because there are multiple synonyms (can have other columns that could be multiple values as well.

What I am trying to do is to create a single row for every business term, and concatenate values (, delimited) so that I get one line item for each business term only.

Currently my SQL script is:

```
SELECT dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm, dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermLongDesc, 
       dbo.TblBusinessTerm.DomainCatID, dbo.TblSystem.SystemName, 
       dbo.TblDomainCat.DataSteward, dbo.TblDomainCat.DomainCatName, 
       dbo.TblField.GoldenSource, dbo.TblField.GTS_table, 
       dbo.TblTableOwner.TableOwnerName, dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym 
FROM   dbo.TblTableOwner INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblBusinessTerm INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblBusinessSynonym ON dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.BusinessTermID INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblField ON dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = dbo.TblField.BusinessTermID INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblSystem INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblTable ON dbo.TblSystem.SystemID = dbo.TblTable.SystemID ON dbo.TblField.TableID = dbo.TblTable.TableID INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblDomainCat ON dbo.TblBusinessTerm.DomainCatID = dbo.TblDomainCat.DomainCatID ON dbo.TblTableOwner.TableOwnerID = dbo.TblDomainCat.DataSteward
```

Is there an easy way to do this that takes performance into consideration - am new to SQL.

Thank you

I have managed to create a with statement that now concatenates my rows:

```
With syn as (
    select [BusinessTermID],
           syns = STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym
                         FROM   dbo.TblBusinessSynonym
                         WHERE  [BusinessTermID] = x.[BusinessTermID]
                             AND    dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym <> ''
                         FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')
    FROM dbo.TblBusinessSynonym AS x
    GROUP BY [BusinessTermID]
)
select * from syn
```

But now how can I use it in the above query where everything links?

Would want to replace `dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym`  with the results from `syn`

Any SQL 2014 developers that can assist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column

Comment: possibly you need to use `CONCAT_WS` for delimited or `CONCAT` for regular values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your   **with**  statement at the very top, without the **select**.
Then write your upper query as it is and change

```
INNER JOIN dbo.TblBusinessSynonym ON dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.BusinessTermID
```

to

```
INNER JOIN syn ON syn.BusinessTermID = dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID
```

That's it

```
With syn as (
    select [BusinessTermID],
           syns = STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym
                         FROM   dbo.TblBusinessSynonym
                         WHERE  [BusinessTermID] = x.[BusinessTermID]
                             AND    dbo.TblBusinessSynonym.Synonym <> ''
                         FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')
    FROM dbo.TblBusinessSynonym AS x
    GROUP BY [BusinessTermID]
)

SELECT dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm, 
       dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermLongDesc, 
       dbo.TblBusinessTerm.DomainCatID, dbo.TblSystem.SystemName, 
       dbo.TblDomainCat.DataSteward, dbo.TblDomainCat.DomainCatName, 
       dbo.TblField.GoldenSource, dbo.TblField.GTS_table, 
       dbo.TblTableOwner.TableOwnerName, syn.syns 
FROM   dbo.TblTableOwner INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblBusinessTerm INNER JOIN
       syn ON dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = syn.BusinessTermID INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblField ON dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = dbo.TblField.BusinessTermID INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblSystem INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblTable ON dbo.TblSystem.SystemID = dbo.TblTable.SystemID ON   dbo.TblField.TableID = dbo.TblTable.TableID INNER JOIN
       dbo.TblDomainCat ON dbo.TblBusinessTerm.DomainCatID = dbo.TblDomainCat.DomainCatID ON dbo.TblTableOwner.TableOwnerID = dbo.TblDomainCat.DataSteward
```

Comment: Managed to get script to run - thank you - but now the SYNS doesn't display as a column header at all. Have reposted ammeded code

Comment: I've added the full query... a LEFT JOIN in **syn** is maybe the better way in your query

Comment: Thank you. Still doesnt like the like `dbo.TblTableOwner.TableOwnerName, syn.syns ` has an issue syn.sys - says multi part identifier could not be bound

Comment: is there a typo on **syn.syns**? it should be **syn.syns**

Comment: No type, has issue on `dbo.syn ON dbo.TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = syn.BusinessTermID ` as well - says the dbo.syn - invalid object name. It does not seem to be picking up the SYN in the with statement and carrying it through to rest of query

Comment: sorry, my fault! **dbo.syn** should be only **syn**

Answer (score 1):

Please use STRING_AGG function. It combines record items in field ans set them in one record separated with specified delimiter.

Details are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: STRING_AGG is not recognized.

Comment: This function isn't supported before MSSQL 2016.

Comment: It was something like this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

Your query is complicated, so I will just post here sample data and how to deal with it in a manner you want. The operation is string aggregation with concatenation, in latest version there's `string_agg` function, that does the work for us. But, as you can't use this function, here's workaround:

```
select * into #tt
from (values (1, '1'),(1, '2'),(2, '1'),(2, '2')) A(id, someStr) 

select id, (select someStr + ',' from #tt where id = [t].id for xml path('')) [grouped]
from #tt [t] group by id
```

Above query groups by `Id` and concaenates all corresponding rows in `someStr` column.

Comment: agreed - query which is simple I have over complicated, but am not able to associated what you have to what I have in respect of table joins etc - have only started in SQL server, so still trying to find my way around.