# How to make row data comma separated in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to make row data comma-separated in SQL Server?

```
CREATE TABLE CountryState
(Country Varchar(15), State Varchar(15))
GO

INSERT INTO CountryState VALUES('India','MH')
INSERT INTO CountryState VALUES('India','DL')
INSERT INTO CountryState VALUES('US','NJ')
INSERT INTO CountryState VALUES('US','NY')
GO

SELECT * FROM CountryState
```

Output:

```
Country State
----------------------------    
India   MH
India   DL
US  NJ
US  NY
```

I require output in following format.

```
Country State
------------------    
India   MH,DL
US          NJ,NY
```

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but you can use `FOR XML PATH` to do it in a reasonably concise way.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country, 
                STUFF((SELECT ',' + State 
                       FROM CountryState cs 
                       WHERE CountryState.Country = cs.Country
                       FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM CountryState;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7036/1).