# select distinct elements from two columns with comma separated in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns like this

```
col1     col2
 a        b
 b        a
 c        d
 d        a
```

I want to get distinct values of these two columns combined with comma separated.
Expected out put is like this

```
a,b,c,d
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL group\_concat function in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example concatenate row values into a variable

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(max)
SELECT @val = COALESCE(@val + ',' + col1, col1)
FROM (SELECT col1
      FROM dbo.twoColumns
      UNION
      SELECT col2
      FROM dbo.twoColumns
      ) x
SELECT @val
```

Demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecd68/1)

Answer (score 2):

try this , its very much easy i think

```
select group_concat(distinct(c)) as d
from 
(
  select col1 c from your_table
  union
  select col2 c from your_table
) as d
```

Comment: I get the data correclty by this method ,but is not comma seperated :(

Comment: `group_concat` is only valid in MySQL and the question is tagged as SQL Server.