# MySQL: Group and flatten elements on a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

If I have a view:

```
Movie             Genre    Actor
-------------------------------------------
Ocean's Twelve    Crime    George Clooney
Ocean's Twelve    Crime    Julia Roberts
Ocean's Twelve    Crime    Brad Pitt
Forrest Gump      Drama    Tom Hanks
```

How would I group by the movie title, but flatten the other columns like so:

```
Movie             Genre    Actor
-------------------------------------------
Ocean's Twelve    Crime    George Clooney, Julia Roberts, Brad Pitt
Forrest Gump      Drama    Tom Hanks
```

Note that if an element is equivalent, it is not repeated (e.g. `Crime`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MySQL**

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT movie, Genre, GROUP_CONCAT(Actor) AS Actor
FROM tableA
GROUP BY movie, Genre
```

**SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT A.movie, A.Genre, MAX(STUFF(B.ActorNames, 1, 1, '')) AS Actor
FROM tableA A 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ' ' + Actor + ',' FROM tableA B 
            WHERE A.movie = B.movie AND A.Genre = B.Genre 
            FOR XML PATH('')
          ) AS B (ActorNames)
GROUP BY A.movie, A.Genre
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select Movie, Genre, group_concat(Actor separator ', ') as `Actors`
from
movies
group by Movie, Genre;
```

Comment: how to do this in sql server ?

Comment: @mhasan Use one of these workarounds [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server). I usually use the `XML PATH` hack.

Answer (score 1):

You need group_concat and group by http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat
Try this

```
select Movie, Genre, group_concat(Actor) from view_name group by Movie
```