# Simulate MySql group_concat in MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat, sql-server-group-concat

I want to run this MySql query in MSSQL.

Is there any possibility to achieve that, by modifying this query?

```
Select 

sku, 
(select group_concat(sku separator ",") 
from catalog_product_entity as _e 
where _e.entity_id in (select product_id from catalog_product_super_link as 
superlink where e.entity_id = superlink.parent_id))

from catalog_product_entity  as e
where type_id = "configurable"

group by sku
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server

Comment: You have the choice of a CLR function, or a rather ugly SQL FOR XML: http://davidduffett.net/post/5334646215/get-a-comma-separated-list-of-values-in-sql-with-for

Comment: @DigitalD rather ugly?  I think it's the best performing option.

Comment: @GoatCO I meant that it just isn't as elegant as a function like `group_concat`, not that it doesn't perform well.

Comment: I guess I will try with XML, as it looks easy. Thanks

Comment: @DigitalD That's fair.