# Concatenating Rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

In SQL Server, I'm using STUFF, XML functionality to use this feature of concatenating strings. After the process i have to update the last element of the record.

My table looks like this:

```
id   category
-------------
1      Pop
1      Rock
2      Pop
3      Rock
```

Same ID category should get append with `|` delimiter

```
Pop|Rock| as Pop|Rock
```

This is the way I'm trying to do. But the `Stuff` and XML is killing my performance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your xml 'stuff' look like? Do you have an example query?

Comment: Show your code. But [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server) indicates that `STUFF, XML` is the way to do it.

Comment: Post your concatenation statetement first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL group\_concat function in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your query look something like this?

```
select id,
       stuff((select '|' + category
              from table t2
              where t2.id = t.id
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as categories
from (select distinct id from table t) t;
```

If you don't use this method, there are other methods in SQL Server, but I think they would have much worse performance.