# How to summarize a query separating with commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of dates with folios, one folio can have multiple dates. The folio is the employee holiday request folio. (SQL Server 2008)

Instead of showing that info like a list I need to show it in the following format:

[image]

Here is the SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ddd2/7

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/8868622/8479

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: This is not a SQL problem, you should be doing display presentation in your UI layer. SQL is a data persistence language, not a data formatting language. i.e. "You are using a hammer to tighten a bolt"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Larry's answer is basically correct (and I'm upvoting it).  But it has some shortcomings:

- It leaves a comma at the end.
- It uses `varchar()` without a length.
- And, it misdescribes the role of `stuff()`.

The string concatenation is actually done by `for xml path`, not by `stuff()`.  `stuff()` just removes the leading comma.

A better formulation dispenses with the unnecessarily levels of subqueries.  In addition, I strongly advocate using date part names in `datepart()`.  Who wants to remember if `mm` means minutes or months, when you can use "minute" and "month" respectively?

```
SELECT hi.holidayid as Folio,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(DATEPART(day, hi2.date) AS VARCHAR(255))
              FROM employee_holiday_item hi2
              WHERE hi2.holidayid = hi.holidayid AND
                    DATEPART(month, hi.date) = DATEPART(month, hi2.date) AND
                    DATEPART(year, hi.date) = DATEPART(year,hi2.date)
              ORDER BY DATEPART(dd,hi2.date)
              FOR XML PATH ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as dates,
       DATEPART(month, hi.date) AS Month,
       DATEPART(year, hi.date) AS Year,
       COUNT(*) AS 'Total Days'
FROM employee_holiday_item hi
GROUP BY hi.holidayid, DATEPART(month,hi.date), DATEPART(year,hi.date)
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ddd2/27) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished using the STUFF function with subqueries.  Syntax would be:

```
SELECT Result2.Folio,
       LEFT(Result2.Dates, LEN(Result2.Dates) -1) AS Dates,
       Result2.Month,
       Result2.Year,
       Result2.[Total Days]
FROM
(
    SELECT Result.Folio,
           STUFF((SELECT ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(dd,hi2.date) AS VARCHAR) + ','
    FROM employee_holiday_item hi2
    WHERE hi2.holidayid = result.Folio
          AND Result.Month = DATEPART(mm,hi2.date)
          AND Result.Year = DATEPART(yyyy,hi2.date)
    ORDER BY DATEPART(dd,hi2.date)
          FOR XML PATH ('') ),1,1,'') AS 'Dates',
          Result.Month,
          Result.Year,
          Result.[Total Days]
    FROM (
          SELECT hi.holidayid as Folio,
                 DATEPART(mm,hi.date) AS Month,
                 DATEPART(yyyy,hi.date) AS Year,
                 COUNT(*) AS 'Total Days'
          FROM employee_holiday_item hi
          GROUP BY hi.holidayid, DATEPART(mm,hi.date), DATEPART(yyyy,hi.date)
        ) AS Result
) AS Result2
```