# Combining columns into one column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

What I'm trying to do is combine multiple columns into one. Say I have a table called `Player`, this table contains multiple columns e.g `name, team, goalie, left back, right back, center back , left midfield.... and description`.

The `description` column would contain `name` + `team` + `left back` , so `description` would be `Ronaldo - Madrid - Forward`. I can populate the description column when a player only has one position, but not for more than one position?

My SQL:

```
select 
    name, team, goalie,
    leftback, rightback, centerback,
    left midfield,
    ......,
    name + ' - ' + team + ' - '+ 
    CASE 
       WHEN goalie = 'yes' THEN 'Goalie' 
       WHEN leftback = 'yes' THEN 'Left Back'
       WHEN rightback = 'yes' THEN 'Right Back'
       WHEN centerback = 'yes' THEN 'Center Back'
       .......
    END AS Description
from 
    player
```

Output:

```
Ronaldo - Madrid - Forward
```

How can I get it to add more then one position, if the player has more than one?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried using a concat over your case?

Comment: @davejal - group conconat is not a function in sql server.

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868604/sql-group-concat-function-in-sql-server

Comment: You really should look at normalizing this. I would have a table for players, another for positions and a bridging table for PlayerPositions. That way a player can play any number of positions.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, sql server 2012

Comment: @SeanLange -- you don't mean "normalizing"

Comment: @Hogan I don't understand your comment. I am referring to normalization.

Comment: @SeanLange - No you mean 3rd normal form.  This data model could be fine depending on the user's requirement.  3rd normal form is not always required or even recommended.  Knee jerk 3rd normal form is a mistake in my opinion... that was my point.

Comment: I would not say that normalizing the 3rd normal is knee jerk. Sure this model can be made to work just like anything in any level of normalized form can be made to work. That doesn't mean it is a good idea. If this were in 3NF it would be easier to work with in my opinion.

Comment: @SeanLange We know nothing about this data and I don't know much about football -- but maybe this is a table of defensive players... then there would never be another position needed than these 3.  This is a possible example why 3NF is not needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
   name,
   team, 
   CASE WHEN goalie = 'yes'      THEN 'Goalie - '      ELSE '' END + 
   CASE WHEN leftback = 'yes'    THEN 'LeftBack - '    ELSE '' END + 
   CASE WHEN rightback = 'yes'   THEN 'RightBack - '   ELSE '' END + 
   CASE WHEN center back = 'yes' THEN 'Center Back - ' ELSE '' END AS Description
```

And you have to remove the last `-` on description

Version for SQL Server +2012

```
WITH cte as (
   SELECT
      name,
      team, 
      IIF(goalie = 'yes',      'Goalie - ', '') + 
      IIF(leftback = 'yes',    'LeftBack - ', '') + 
      IIF(rightback = 'yes',   'RightBack - ', '') + 
      IIF(center back = 'yes', 'Center Back - ', '') AS Description
   FROM Players
)
SELECT name,
       team,
       CASE LEN(Description) 
          WHEN 0 THEN Description 
          ELSE LEFT(Description, LEN(Description) - 3)
       END
FROM cte
```

Check In the comment for a version using `STUFF`

Comment: hint... STUFF() with default of ` - `

Comment: It should be pointed out... `IIF` is not portable and is only in version greater than or equal to SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Hogan, OP say he has 2012

Comment: Answers on Stackoverflow are not intended for one person.  If an answer only helps one person it should be closed.  100s, 1000s or more people are going to look at and use this answer.

Comment: @Hogan Dont scold me I put both  solutions :P. Help me with the STUFF?. I was going to do a LEFT with lenght.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, the description column is coming back `NULL`

Comment: @AndroidAL The first version need it a `ELSE ''` part. fix it Still working on the remove the last `- `

Comment: @AndroidAL Ups I lose the changes, check now.

Comment: @Hogan Yes looks like I would have to use a cte and one iif for when length = 0. I tought was like a regexp replace. Will leave the `LEFT` version thanks

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - no problem and don't take it as a scold -- it was intended positive -- your good answer should be seen by and useful to many.

Comment: @Hogan Dont worry I took it as positive, that was the :P part  sorry if wasnt obvious the bazinga tone :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of the `CASE` statements and prefer to avoid them when I can. You could get away with something like:

```
select stuff (
              isnull(replace(replace(goalie,'no',''),'yes',' - Goalie'),'')
            + isnull(replace(replace(leftback,'no',''),'yes',' - Leftback'),'')
            + isnull(replace(replace(rightback,'no',''),'yes',' - Rightback'),'')
              ....
              ,1,3,''
             ) as 'Description'
  from Player
```

if the only values for `goalie` and the like are 'yes', 'no', and NULL.

Comment: I was testing the stuff, what if player isnt any of those category, like `defense` will stuff work with empty string and return empty string?

Comment: It would return NULL. This does also assume that at least one 'yes' will be there. But, you could wrap the STUFF in an ISNULL to have it return an empty string (or something else) when the player has no 'yes' values.

Comment: Then similar to what I did. Thanks.