# How to find the most common columns across all tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create a matrix for all the common columns used across multiple tables in a database sorted in descending order. For example **ProductSerialNo** is used in three tables.

| ColumnName | Tables | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ProductSerialNo | Product,ProductModels,Inventory | 3 |
| EquipmentNo | Equipment,Warehouse | 2 |

Comment: Show us the code you have tried and what part of it you are stuck with

Comment: How do I mark my own answer as solved? lol :)

Comment: @Montreal: Put it into an answer box (rather than into the question) and then accept your own answer. That is not only allowed, but actually [actively encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As a data source you can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), or you can join sys.columns and sys.tables.
2. To just get the number of tables, `COUNT(*)` with `GROUP BY` will suffice.
3. To get the list of comma-separated tables, use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) in SQL Server 2017 or higher. If you have an older version of SQL Server, workarounds can be found in this related question:

   [SQL group_concat function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8868604/87698)

---

All of the above combined yields ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YKggb6AP)):

```
SELECT column_name, STRING_AGG(table_name, ', ') AS tables, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM information_schema.columns
 GROUP BY column_name
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: @Montreal: That would diminish the educational value of this exercise: I want to help you become a better developer, not do your work for free. After reading the documentation linked to in my answer, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I am an SQL expert and can solve the problem million different ways. As I have been super busy at work, thought I could ask for help from the community in here and perhaps help others who have the same problem. Thereby contributing to the knowledge base of stackoverflow.
String_Agg does not work in this situation.
Thank you anyways! :)

Comment: @Montreal: I see. Well, StackOverflow is primarily meant as a platform to get expert advice if you *need knowledge*, not as a means to get others to do grunt work for you. That's a common misconception, though, so I don't blame you. We're all super-busy. :-)

Comment: @Montreal: BTW, I do think that STRING_AGG should work here. Unfortunately, sqlfiddle is currently down, but I'll try to create an example when it's back up.

Comment: @Montreal: String_agg works fine for me (see updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
select distinct A.COLUMN_NAME,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + B.TABLE_NAME
         from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B
         where A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') AS [TABLE_NAMES]
        , X.COUNT
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
LEFT JOIN 
(
select COLUMN_NAME, COUNT(1) [COUNT]
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
) X ON X.COLUMN_NAME = A.COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY X.COUNT DESC
```

Thank you everyone! :)